# R clear code completion suggestions

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

It seems like R studio shows me code completion suggestions from datasets that I haven't used in ages. I've searched everywhere, but can't figure out how to delete these old suggestions from the drop-down menu. Where does R get its code completion suggestions from, and how can I delete irrelevant suggestions?

Comment: Do you save objects to global environment after each session?

Comment: try rm() to remove those from your global environment, then you won't see them again.

Comment: Probably you are saving your workspace every time you quit and loading it when you start. I recommend Tools > Global Options then set "Save workspace to RData on exit" to "Never". You will then need to take responsibility to deliberately save any objects you want to keep around, but that is a good habit to form - better to save the script to create the object and run it as needed, saving only objects that are time consuming to create.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor, I think this will take care of the problem in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Environment tab, click on the broom icon.  You will be prompted with a dialog "confirm remove objects".  If you click yes this will clear all data from the environment.  If you save upon exit your will start with a clean environment.